# How to control which SQS will pull the message from the SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have a SNS with 2 SQS's listening to it.

Is there a way to pull a message in to a specific SQS? I was hoping there will be something based on the regexp, or some message headers or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. The only way would be to have multiple SNS topics that publish to the appropriate queue.